# Run a Rails cron job every business quarter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I'm using whenever gem to manage my cron tab.

What would be the appropriate expression to get a task to run every business quarter: Jan 1, Apr 1, July 1, October 1

This is my guess, but I have no way of knowing if its correct:

```
every 3.months, at: "January 1st, 12:00AM" do
  runner "Points::Resetter.reset_quarterly"
end
```

which results in this crontab entry:

```
0 12,0 1 1,4,7,10 *
```

Comment: You could schedule a rake task that checks something similar to this everynight: `[1,4,7,10].include?(Date.today.month)`

Comment: You can check the cron setting with [this site](http://cronchecker.net/check?statement=0+12%2C0+1+1%2C4%2C7%2C10+*+script.sh)

Comment: Shot in the dark, as I've never used this gem before, but try taking out the comma in `"January 1st, 12:00AM"`. It seems your code has it running twice on each target day, and that was the most suspicious part.

Comment: @chrisf saying "January 1st 12:00AM" results in: 0 0 1 1,4,7,10 *

Comment: I think you have to run it every month, and then leave it to the Rake task to check whether it's a business quarter.

Comment: @chrisf according to the site you suggested: http://cronchecker.net/check?utf8=%E2%9C%93&statement=0+0+1+1%2C4%2C7%2C10+*+script.sh&button= it appears like this is correct.  But someone in the rubyonrails irc said something about the * on the end maybe causing problems